# Java: Using other files in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

So in order to do part of my assignment I have to use outside files.  And I believe I've done this correctly, but I'm still getting an error.

Here is how my project is set up:
[image: Eclipse setup]

As you can see I'm trying to load the audio 2001.mid and the image nightsky.jpeg.  Both of those are located in the resources file inside of project three.  I don't see what's wrong, however I'm am completely new to this type of thing.  So any help is appreciated.

Also just not note STDdraw is in the lib folder.  there is no problem with that either.

This is the error I get when trying to run it.

```
 Mar 24, 2014 4:00:24 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
 WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs
 at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image
 resources/nightsky.jpeg not found  at
 StdDraw.getImage(StdDraw.java:656)     at
 StdDraw.picture(StdDraw.java:671)  at NBody.main(NBody.java:17)
```

Comment: You are providing correct path to the file (if of course file is under resources/someFile).

If you just want to see how the files works you can e.g. open the text file (by standard library) and print it.

However, if you want to play this midi sound or draw something can you provide links to the libraries which you are using? It would be simplier.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, `resources` is set up just like `src`, with the same package structure.  You then add both `resources` and `src` as source folders in Eclipse.

[image]

Now that they are both source folders, the resource files will be copied into your `bin` folder, right next to the class files that will try to read them.  You should then be able to reference them like...

```
StdAudio.play("2001.mid");  // note, no resources folder prefix
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are inside one folder(you are in `src`). So the location of `resources` is actually here: `../resources`

You can check if you have the right path with this code:

```
File image = new File("../resources/nightsky.jpeg");
        if(image.exists() && !image.isDirectory()) {
             System.out.println("Image found!");

        }
```